# How can I remove external storage with root priviligies or not?

Tags: android

I have `isExternalStorageRemovable()` in my code. After calling this function, anyone want to remove the external storage. However, I do not know how. How can I remove external storage with root priviligies or not ?

Preferable answer ;

- eject
- safely remove device